# Drawing 3D text using LWJGL

Tags: opengl, 3d, lwjgl

I've been searching for a while for a way to write 3d text in openGL using LWJGL and Slick but I couldn't find appropriate tutorial on how to do it. Is it actually possible to render 3D text using LWJGL and Slick? If not, is there another library that can do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by "possible"? 3D text is just a mesh that happens to be in the shape of letters. LWJGL is just a Java interface to OpenGL, which is perfectly capable of drawing meshes. So it can in theory draw 3D text, so long as you provide the meshes to do so.

Do LWJGL and Slick provide built-in means to *create* 3D text meshes from strings? No. You'll have to use some other library to do that, or write one yourself.

Comment: I figured that out. Then, I converted to Unity instead of writing opengl. Thanks anyway.